# Docker nginx wont start saying my file is a directory (windows)

Tags: docker, nginx

Im trying to run my docker-compose file but i keep getting directories instead of files:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: bash
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./../:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
```

in folder ../ i have a file `nginx.site.conf`

when i sart the container: `docker-compose -f scripts/prod/docker-compose.yml run web bash` and i go the the directory i try to cat my file nginx.site.conf it doesn't work saying its a directory. Also i can open this directory but its empty.

i expect it to be a file:

```
somehow i can jump into it as a directory?
root@e360b4930cca:/etc/nginx/conf.d# cd nginx.site.conf/
root@e360b4930cca:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.site.conf# ls
```

How do i fix this? i run on windows and i haven't changed anything to my setup. Only have got the default windows protection (no virus scanner) enabled, even with app and browser control disabled it doesnt work.

What are the reasons docker turns my file into a directory?

Comment: Did it work before (does "i haven't changed anything to my setup" mean that you got it working previously in the same environment)? And did you try to run it in the Linux VM with the same working directory layout (and possibly with different storage drivers, but I'm unsure whether storage driver issue may affect a volume)?

Comment: Try without the trailing `/`

Comment: @DanilaKiver Yea it worked previously, I did a docker update a while ago (it worked afterwards). I specified the exact file to map first instead of the directory but that also didnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Actually coming back after a computer restart it worked again.

I think something in docker itself or maybe behind the scenes windows updates caused this.

Even restarting docker didn't work, i had to restart windows.

Comment: I recall that when I perform an update on my Linux box, and Docker is updated too, it stops working until the box is restarted. That happened quite frequently, so, I think that rebooting the machine after updating Docker may become a rule of thumb. Anyway, congrats =)